# $f(x+\frac{y}{2})-f(x-\frac{y}{2})=2x^2y+5y^2$. Find $\frac{d f(3)}{dx}= f'(3)=?$

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

> $f(x+\frac{y}{2})-f(x-\frac{y}{2})=2x^2y+5y^2$
>
> $\frac{d f(3)}{dx}= f'(3)=?$

As there is no information on whether $y$ is a function or a constant, I believe it must be treated as a constant. Then, we need to know the value of $y$ in order to set $x+\frac{y}{2}=3$ and find the derivative.

How can we solve this problem?

Comment: The way to interpret $x$ and $y$ here is that you can put any values for $x$ and $y$ (independently) and then $f$ will satisfy the given equation. To solve your problem, plug in $x=3$, divide the equation by $y$ and then consider the limit as $y$ goes to zero.

Comment: @quarague So, I got. $\lim_{y\to 0} f(3+\frac{y}{2})-f(3-\frac{y}{2})=\lim_{y\to 0} 18 + 5y$. But then $f(3)-f(3)=18$. Can you please tell me what am I missing?

Comment: Check your algebra, you need to divide both sides of the equation by $y$.

Comment: Oh, yes, I got it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\frac{df(x)}{dx} = \lim_{y \to 0} \left(\frac{f(x + \frac{y}{2}) - f(x - \frac{y}{2})}{y}\right) = \lim_{y \to 0} \frac{2x^2y + 5y^2}{y} = \lim_{y \to 0} 2x^2 + 5y = 2x^2
$$

Therefore $f'(3) = 18$